# firebase auth applyActionCode method does not turn emailVerified to true

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing firebase authentication system where a user is sent email to verify email adr. I got everything working eventually. The user signs up and the email (with the link) is sent to the signed up edmail adr. I use custom email action handler (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) to respond to a click on the link. On my node.js express route, I get oobCode (which firebase documentation say is "A one-time code, used to identify and verify a request") and pass it as an argument to firebase.auth().applyActionCode(oobCode) which returns a void promise when resolved. see code below.

```
   firebase.auth().applyActionCode(oobCode)
        .then( () => {
          return admin.auth().updateUser(currentUser.uid, {
            emailVerified: true,
          })
        })
        .then( () => {
          return res.status(301).redirect(`../unps/${currentUser.uid}`)
        })
        .catch( (error) => {
          return res.status(500).json({ unp_error: `error message: ${error.message} - error code: 
   ${error.code}` })
        });
```

My undestanding of the documentation is that, applyActionCode method, if resolved, will set the emailVerified to true but this does not happen even though there is no error. I had to call updateUser to change emailVerified to true. Shouldnt this be done automatically by the method applyActionCode if a valid oobCode is presented as argument? What am I missinmg? Pleaase help?

Answer (score 3):

All information about the Firebase Authentication user in your application code is taken from the ID token. This ID token is valid for an hour, and automatically refreshed by the SDK about 5 minutes before it expires. Until the token is refreshed, it may not reflect the latest value of `emailVerified` or other information about that user profile on the server.

It is indeed normal that you need to force a refresh of the token, to get the updated status before it auto-refreshes. When you do that, you shouldn't have to call `admin.auth().updateUser(...)` though.